# DN value from raster to vector tool (QGIS 2.0)

Tags: qgis, raster

I am using QGIS 2.0 to convert a DEM to vectors, then create polygons of zones of slopes. However, I am unsure of in what units my new "DN" column is. It has lost of precision of z-values from my original XYZ points, and am not sure how it compares.

Comment: Neither do we unless we know which data you used and how you calculated the slopes. At least in QGIS depending on the projection you have to apply a z-factor to get values in degree (°)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dn stands fro Digital Number. When you convert a raster to a polygon it will create a vector record for each cell of the raster (DEM). The numeric value from the raster will be written to the attribute of the vector as the Dn. So, if you have a cell with a height of 124 meters, the vector record for that cell will have a Dn value of 124. The precision issue is that the number is being stored as an integer, and not as a float.